# When using registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier, how do I init UITableViewCell iVars?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am loading custom subclassed `UITableViewCell`s from nib.

My view controller `viewDidLoad` method uses `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier`.
My view controller's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method uses `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to load the cell, but I never alloc/init the cell.

**ViewController:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tV registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"VersatileIntTFCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:kTFInt];
    self.tV.delegate=self;
    self.tV.dataSource=self;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Int TextField";
    VersatileIntTFCell *cell = (VersatileIntTFCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];   
    return cell;

}
```

The table view appears fine, and the cells appear fine.

Now, I am starting to write the subclasses of `UITableViewCell`. My subclasses each have some @property iVars (they are not `IBOutlets`). I would like to init these in the `init` method of the `UITableViewCell` subclass, but that doesn't appear to ever get called. I can init them in the viewController's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but I want to avoid this. I want to do it in the `UITableViewCell` subclass. Is this possible? If so, how/where/when?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Override the `awakeFromNib` method and put your code there rather than in the init.

From the docs:

> The nib-loading infrastructure sends an awakeFromNib message to each
>   object recreated from a nib archive, but only after all the objects in
>   the archive have been loaded and initialized. When an object receives
>   an awakeFromNib message, it is guaranteed to have all its outlet and
>   action connections already established. You must call the super
>   implementation of awakeFromNib to give parent classes the opportunity
>   to perform any additional initialization they require.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to initialise any UIView after it's loaded from a nib, you should override `initWithCoder`. `awakeFromNib` might also be useful. See 'Methods to Override' in the UIView reference.

Comment: This should be marked as the accepted answer. awakeFromNib is the function to use and not initWithCoder since subviews have not been loaded until they are actually needed. They are loaded in awakeFromNib though.

Answer (score 1):

There's a method `prepareForReuse` that you can use.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse